# My SQL PHP Generated edit button is only working once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

I'm developing a web application which is like a notepad or a to-do list with php sql html css jquery

The query gets the list at index page and displays it and on displaying it adds a button with an "edit" class.

**When they press on the edit the edit works but only once after submitting.**

On submitting the button launches an **ajax** call with jQuery to another PHP file which edits the data and and displays all the items from the database again.

There's also an "add item" button which adds a new item. Which on submit adds a new item and also gets everything again from the database and displays it (also ajax).

The bug is **either after submitting a new item or after editing, the edit button stops working**

Please check the snippet below -- snippet 1 is the jquery, snippet 2 is the file to be run on ajax call, and snippet 3 is the index php file:

```js
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        
        textarea = $("#textarea").val();
        date = $("#date").val();
        
        if(textarea == "" || date == ""){
            $("#message").html("<span class='error'>Make sure you didn't leave anything empty");
        }
        else{
            $("#message").html("");
            submitItem();
            $("#contentCont").fadeOut(200);
        }
    });
    
    $(".edit").click(function(){
        i = "edit";
        itemID = $(this).attr("name");
        var dateValue = $("#date"+itemID).text();
        var statusValue = $("#status"+itemID).attr("name");
        var textboxValue = $("#textbox"+itemID).text();
        var categoryValue = $("#category"+itemID).text().toLowerCase();
        $("#contentCont").fadeIn(200);
        $("#textarea").val(textboxValue);
        $("#date").val(dateValue);
        $("#categories").val(categoryValue).prop("selected",true);
        $("#status").val(statusValue).prop("selected",true);
    });
    function submitItem(){
        textarea = $("#textarea").val();
        status = $("#status").val();
        category = $("#categories").val();
        date = $("#date").val();
            
        var ajaxReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajaxReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("todoCont").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        }
        ajaxReq.open("POST","../php/addItem.php",true);
        ajaxReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        ajaxReq.send("textarea="+textarea+"&category="+category+"&status="+status+"&date="+date+"&itemID="+itemID+"&i="+i);
    }
```

```css
<?php
session_start();
require("server.php");
$cnx = new mysqli($server_name,$server_username,$server_password,$db);

$category = validate($_POST["category"]);
$item = $_POST["textarea"];
$date = $_POST["date"];
$status = validate($_POST["status"]);
$userID = $_SESSION["userID"];
$itemID = $_POST["itemID"];
$i = $_POST["i"];


$searchForCategoryID = "SELECT * FROM categories where userID='$userID' AND categoryname = '$category'";

$result = $cnx->query($searchForCategoryID);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$categoryID = $row["CategoryID"];
if ($i === "new"){
    $addItem = "INSERT INTO Items(userID,ItemValue,DueDate,CategoryID,Status) VALUES ($userID, '$item' , '$date' , $categoryID,'$status')";
    $cnx->query($addItem);
}

else if ($i === "edit"){
    $editItem = "UPDATE Items SET ItemValue='$item' , DueDate='$date' , CategoryID = $categoryID,Status='$status' WHERE itemID = $itemID " ;
    $cnx->query($editItem);
}

$getTableRows = "SELECT * FROM Items WHERE userID = $userID ORDER BY DueDate";
$result = $cnx->query($getTableRows);

if($cnx->error){
    echo "Could not get your stuff";
}

if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while ($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $getCategory = "SELECT CategoryName FROM Categories WHERE CategoryID = " . $rows["CategoryID"] . ";";
        $result2 = $cnx->query($getCategory);
        $rows2 = $result2->fetch_assoc();
        if ($rows["Status"] == "ongoing"){
            $status = "ongoing";
        }else
        if ($rows["Status"] == "overdue"){
            $status = "overdue";
        }else
        if ($rows["Status"] == "done"){
            $status = "done";
        }
        echo '  <div class="box-container">
                    <div class="right">
                      <div class="textbox">
                        <span id="textbox'.$rows["itemID"].'">'. $rows["ItemValue"] .'</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="footer">
                        <div class="status '. $status .'" id="status'.$rows["itemID"].'" name="'.$status.'"></div>
                        <span class="date" id="date'.$rows["itemID"].'">'.$rows["DueDate"].'</span>
                        <span class="category" id="category'.$rows["itemID"].'">'.ucfirst($rows2["CategoryName"]).'</span>
                        <button type="button" name="'. $rows["itemID"] .'" class="btn btn-info edit">Edit</button>
                      </div>
 
                    </div>
                </div>';
    }
}
?>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php session_start();?>
<?php
include("server.php");
$cnx = new mysqli($server_name,$server_username,$server_password,$db);
$userID = $_SESSION["userID"];

<!--This is how the info is shown and the EDIT button is made-->
 echo '  <div class="box-container">
                    <div class="right">
                      <div class="textbox">
                        <span id="textbox'.$rows["itemID"].'">'. $rows["ItemValue"] .'</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="footer">
                        <div class="status '. $status .'" id="status'.$rows["itemID"].'" name="'.$status.'"></div>
                        <span class="date" id="date'.$rows["itemID"].'">'.$rows["DueDate"].'</span>
                        <span class="category" id="category'.$rows["itemID"].'">'.ucfirst($rows2["CategoryName"]).'</span>
                        <button type="button" name="'. $rows["itemID"] .'" class="btn btn-info edit">Edit</button>
                      </div>
 
                    </div>
                </div>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to register your events more globally:

```
$("body").on("click", "#submit", function(){
});
```

and

```
$("body").on("click", ".edit", function(){
});
```

Comment: I just tried it, it didn't work , feels like the event listener is not working when everything is deleted and re-entered :/

Comment: there can be another problem with duplicate IDs. See the generated source code (after first iteration) if you don't have #submit twice

Comment: it should be good to post also complete html (where is #submit?)
and console output too

Comment: there was a bug (didn't use jquery for a long time) try the new solution

Comment: I see that you have changed your code to use `on`, probably after looking at my answer ;)

Comment: yes. but registered to body element. I didn't notice, he uses click method and not on method (and copy pasted code). Your solution is registered to original element, so is not working and is totally the same like $("#submit").click(function(){});

Answer (score 0):

You need to delegate as the element is getting created dynamically.

Change the below line:

```
$(".edit").click(function(){
```

to:

```
$(".edit").on('click', function(){
```

And the same applies for

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
```

to

```
$("#submit").on('click', function(){
```

Comment: your code is the same. $().click(function(){}) is a shortcut for $().on("click", function(){})

Comment: you need to register events to persistent DOM element like body

Comment: There is difference.. `on` would work even on DOM that is generated dynamically unlike `click()`

Comment: see the documentation. there is a difference, but not in case you wrote. You need to register event on persistent element and define selector inside on method